# Thread Safe JAXB unmarshaller in rabbitmq listener java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jaxb, amqp, unmarshalling

`I use jaxb unmarshaller in rabbitmq listener method with one quee multiple consumer . As you know jaxb unmarshaller is not thread safe so my unmarshalled object different from orginal message. How can i deal with this problem. That's my code :` public class NotficationListener{
@RabbitListener(queues = "FASTQE0132", containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")

```
` public void handleMessage(final byte[] message) throws Throwable {
        JAXBContext jbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FastIstem.class);
        Unmarshaller um = jbc.createUnmarshaller();
FastIstem fastIstem=
                (FastIstem) um.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(message));

            synchronized (fastIstem) {
                endPointServiceForInput.executeService(message,
                        fastIstem, fastIslemTipModelList);//The method throws exception because the fastIstem values not equals to orginal message when i use multiple consumers.

            }
}
}
`
```

```
`@Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JAXBException {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);
        factory.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
        factory.setConsecutiveIdleTrigger(1);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(5000);
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
`
```

I tired use fastIstem object with synchronized block but is not working. Also i tired this codes but not working
`public class Xml2Class {
private ThreadLocal unmarshaller;

```
public Xml2Class(JAXBContext jaxb) {
    this.unmarshaller = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> safe(jaxb::createUnmarshaller));
}

public Object unmarshal(InputStream is) throws JAXBException {
        return unmarshaller.get().unmarshal(is);
}

public Xml2Class() {
    this(safe(() -> JAXBContext.newInstance(FastIstem.class)));
}

private static <T> T safe(Callable<T> fn) {
    try {
        return fn.call();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
static final JAXBContext context;

static {
    try {
        context = initContext();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
private static JAXBContext initContext() throws JAXBException {
    return JAXBContext.newInstance(FastIstem.class);
}
```

}``